# how to close popup by clicking outside popup and how to remove class on clicking outside popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used some random tutorial to add popup to my webpage. Is there a way to make it so a popup closes when you click outside it/click on a different one.

I've tried adding an id close to a div outside popup but it closes the popup when clicked inside the popup also, Can i get some help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center">
    <h2>Popup</h2>
    <a class="show-cta" id="open" href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
      <!--  model popup start  -->
    <div class="modal-container" id="modalContainer">     
        <div class="modal">
        </div>         
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

basic model popup css

`<style>
a.show-cta{
    background-color: #ea1420;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    text-decoration: none;

}

.modal-container{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal-container.show{
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 85rem;
    height: 470px;
    box-shadow: 0 .2rem .4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);    
}

</style>`

How to remove class 'show' by clicking outside popup.

````
<script>

window.onclick=function(){
 
 const open = document.getElementById('open');
 const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modalContainer');
 const close = document.getElementById('close');
```
 
 open.addEventListener('click', () => {
     modalContainer.classList.add('show');
 });
 
 close.addEventListener('click', () => {
      modalContainer.classList.remove('show');                 
 });
}

</script>
````

Comment: Try to add `z-index` property to `modalContainter` style more then zero

Answer (score 0):

You can add `addEventListener` on the `modal-container`
and raise the `z-index` of the `modal`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modalContainer').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;
    $('#modalContainer').remove()
});
```